# I don't understand how to write an IF/THEN statement in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How can this POSSIBLY be happening?

```
var X = db.getItem('ShowDeleted');
console.log(X);
if (X) {
    console.log(1);
} else {
    console.log(2);
}
```

In Firebug, I'm getting:

```
true
1
false
1
```

As I fire the snippet in question.

Edit: I apologize for using db. in my example.  db=localStorage.

Comment: Based on the code you have shown, it _can't_ happen. There aren't even 4 `console.log` calls in what you have provided.

Comment: what is the type of your variable *x*?

Comment: Seems this is running twice. Your syntax is correct.

Comment: Your `X` is probably a string. Every non-zero length string is implicitly converted to `true` when it is used somewhere where boolean value is expected (like in `if` statement).

Comment: Show us some more code.  Not sure if it's running twice.  Hard to tell since we only have a small code snippet.  If it were running twice, I would expect...  true, 1, false, 2 or true, 1, true, 1.  Unless of course, as ghik has mentioned, it's a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ghik pointed out, your `X` value is probably being returned as a string. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9q4AX/) is a jsfiddle script that works properly when set as a boolean, and displays your bizarre behaviour when set as a string

```
//boolean version
var X =true;
console.log(X);
if (X) {
    console.log(1);
} else {
    console.log(2);
}
var X =false;
console.log(X);
if (X) {
    console.log(1);
} else {
    console.log(2);
}
//outputs
true
1
false 
2


//String version
var X ='true';
console.log(X);
if (X) {
    console.log(1);
} else {
    console.log(2);
}
var X ='false';
console.log(X);
if (X) {
    console.log(1);
} else {
    console.log(2);
}
//outputs
true
1
false 
1
```

Answer (score 2):

What I imagine is happening (although it's really impossible to tell without knowing what type `db.getItem` returns) is that `X` ends up being some nonboolean value.  Then the `if` statement is always evaluates to `true` because the variable is some value other than `0`.  That is, if it returns a string `"false"` (or really any object for that matter) the following always follows the `if` branch, not the `else`

```
if("false"){
  //do something
} else {
  //do something else
}
```

You need to make sure that you're actually evaluating a boolean, not some other value.